# Size of SQL Server tempDB for Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, tempdb

Is there an expected size of tempDB for a Data Warehouse application.
Is 10 gigs excessive?
It's hit by frequent large queries.
The Data Warehouse itself is 50 gigs.

I'm using SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't seem terribly out of line.  If it's a problem, have you looked at your worst performing queries or your queries that use the most tempdb?

SQL Server 2000 doesn't have as many useful tools to monitor this as later versions have with DMVs etc, but you can [use the profiler](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/)

https://web.archive.org/web/20080509095429/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/why-is-tempdb-full-and-how-can-i-prevent-this-from-happening.html